# Hangfire on Cosmos DB and Azure - suddenly start send many requests

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, hangfire

I have `Hangfire` deployed on `Azure` and using `Cosmos DB`. It worked correctly. But suddenly start send many requests to database. Number of requests has increased significantly as you can see on screen. And it still is the same. I don't know what is the reason. There was no deploy in this time.
[image: Requests to Cosmos DB from Hangfire]

---

When I call this query in Cosmos DB:

```
SELECT * FROM c where TimestampToDateTime(c._ts * 1000) > '2021-04-08T22:00:00'
```

I see only three items, sometimes, four and sometimes six:

```
[
    {
        "server_id": "edd-deployment-66996d6756-dcxzr:1:938b65a7-196d-4d30-adc5-90101c2781a9",
        "workers": 25,
        "queues": [
            "default"
        ],
        "created_on": 1617290983,
        "last_heartbeat": 1617925294,
        "type": 1,
        "id": "60F6F9F583AC75F979484394ED71F878",
        "_rid": "QO5WANzKklgpmtIBAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/QO5WAA==/colls/QO5WANzKklg=/docs/QO5WANzKklgpmtIBAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"3b00c703-0000-0100-0000-606f94ae0000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1617925294
    },
```

These tasks are `heartbeat` and they are update all time. But it was in previous time too.

Comment: Check the Request metrics to understand what type of requests are now increasing which might map to some particular flow in the application logic. Also, does the number of requests map to an increase in RU consumption?

Comment: Yes, RU is higher and we have to pay more for service. This is a problem because it happened suddenly. We don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what requests are being made to the database to find out what is causing the problem.

Possible problems are:

- Recurring jobs executing in parralell
- Job failing and generating several retry events

Comment: I added response to your answer